# Creating Back up image of Linux using Altiris DS 6.9 SP5

Tags: linux, backup, centos, altiris

I am using Altiris Deployment Solution 6.9 SP5. I want to create a back up image of Linux OS/CentOS. I have created the job using the following tasks:

1. Reboot to automation
2. Create Disk Image
3. Reboot

The jobs is stuck at step 2 as the machine goes on sleep immediately after reboot. It tries to send Wake-on-Lan signal but that doesn't work.

Is there a way to keep the system alive until the job completes successfully.

The machine am trying to take back up of is a B series blade server. I could not find any power setting in the BIOS settings to enable Wake-on-Lan.

Please correct me if the process listed above to create a back-up image in DS 6.9 is incorrect.

A quick help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I used the option "Quick Disk Image" (right click on a computer) when i need to perform a backup.  Set the job to do not schedule and then configure the task as needed.